# how to sync the local git repository to different remote one?

Tags: git

I setup a git server days ago in the lab. I am trying to create two repositories on the same server with name origin and myprj so to maintain two separate projects. I am following the post [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations) and [GIT repository layout for server with multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732020/git-repository-layout-for-server-with-multiple-projects)

I create a new repository as

```
git remote add myprj https://xxx.yyy.zzz/repo.git
```

and it shows me

```
git remote
origin
myprj
```

I create a clone on the local computer and it clones the origin repository and master branch, in which I have two files a.txt and b.txt. But the new repository myprj does not have any file yet.

I am trying to fetch the myprj as

```
git fetch myprj
```

I got

```
From https://xxx.yyy.zzz/repo.git
 * [new branch]    master    -> myprj/master
 * [new branch]    myprj     -> myprj/myprj
```

But this does not update the local folder. I also try

```
git pull myprj master
From https://xxx.yyy.zzz/repo.git
 * branch    master    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

But the local folder is not sync with the remote myprj repository. I think I must misunderstand the concepts on repository. I am learning how to easily switch between different repositories on the same server so I can maintain it locally and upload to the remote server later.

p.s. I clone origin/master to the local folder which .git created by git client. In the local folder, I create A.txt and then

```
git checkout -b origin/master
git add A.txt
git commit -a -m 'this is on origin master'
```

then I create B.txt for myprj only

```
git checkout -b myprj/master
git add B.txt
git commit -a -m 'this is on myprj master'
```

What I expect is after I checkout different repository, should I see the local file changed to refect which files contained in the repository by the client? I found that if I create branch on the same repository, switching between different branch will see the different contents.

Comment: so you have two files on origin and local, and nothing on myprj. Why don't you push your files to myprj to have it in sync?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I mean when I create the myprj, I don't have file to upload there. But I am trying to upload something there my seems everything I commit will go to origin/master instead.

Comment: Could you mark which of the above commands are run on server and which on client?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean where I run those commands? All commands are run on the git bash client, but I think the one with remote will act on the remote site (let me know if I am wrong).

Comment: Please, instead of describing what you do, post a transcript. "I create a new repository as

git remote add myprj https://xxx.yyy.zzz/repo.git 
"  -- if that's really what you did -- didn't create a repository at all.

Comment: The link is not accessible from internet, it is an internal server, I am showing an example there. Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: It seems to me that what you're trying to achieve is to work with two remote repositories that contain _different_ code. In that case, just clone them into two different directories; don't use `git remote`. That command is only useful when you have multiple remote repositories that contain the _same_ code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do. I think I get your suggestions, it looks good to clone that into different folders instead. thanks.

Comment: by the way, if you want to have a mirror remote project, you can use the `git push --mirror https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git` to achieve that.